# Docker-Compose not displaying web content

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose

I am having some issues viewing the content of a web page (swagger document) using the URL from docker container.

I tried these docker-compose commands:

```
> docker-compose build 

> docker-compose up -d
```

However, I am not able to view the webpage (or swagger - since its an API).

When I run `Docker-Compose` from `Visual studio` by clicking on the Run button, it works and I am able to access the `swagger` document. However, when I stop VS, then I am not able to access it by navigating to the provided URLS. How can I fix this?

```
- Solution
  - My.Web
    - Dockerfile
  - My.Lib
  - Solution.sln
  - docker-compose.yml
  - docker-compose.dcproj
  - docker-compose.override.yml
```

**My folder structure looks like follows:**

My **Docker-Compose.yml** looks like below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  my.web:
    container_name: my-9
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT:STAGING
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443" 
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: My.Web\Dockerfile
```

My **Dockerfile** looks like below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app


ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:80
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["My.Web/My.Web.csproj", "My.Web/"]
COPY ["My.Lib/My.Lib.csproj", "My.Lib/"]
RUN dotnet restore "My.Web/My.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/My.Web"
RUN dotnet build "My.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "My.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "My.Web.dll"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've used the webapi template as a starting point for your application, then there's some code like this in your Program.cs file

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

That makes it so Swagger is only available when your app is running in a development environment. A container is not considered development by default.

You've set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `STAGING` in your docker-compose file. It needs to be `Development` for `app.Environment.IsDevelopment()` to return true.

If you want to keep your environment as `STAGING`, you need to alter Program.cs, so Swagger will be available. Either by having it test for `STAGING` or by completely removing the if statement.

If you remove the if statement, that would make Swagger be available always and might be considered a security risk by some.

Comment: I also tried it with `DEVELOPMENT` and I still see the same result.

Comment: You have a colon in that line in your docker-compose file. It should be an equals sign.